# How do I select this non-visible link lacking id with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: php, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select this link, 'User Requested'. It appears when the mouse hovers over the menu.

[image: Imgur]

It has this HTML

```
<ul class="k-widget k-reset k-header k-menu k-menu-horizontal" id="menu" data-role="menu" tabindex="0" role="menubar" aria-activedescendant="menu_mn_active">
...
<li class="k-item js-first-level k-state-default k-state-border-down" role="menuitem" style="z-index: 100;">
  <span class="k-link js-first-level k-state-active k-state-border-down" target="">Reports/Analytics<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s"></span></span>
  <div class="k-animation-container" style="width: 152px; height: 145px; margin-left: -2px; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px; padding-bottom: 4px; overflow: visible; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 10002; top: 27px; left: -2.703125px;">
    <ul class="k-group k-menu-group k-popup k-reset k-state-border-up" role="menu" data-role="popup"
    style="max-height: 578px; overflow: auto; display: block; font-size: 12px; font-family: &#39;Open Sans&#39;, sans-serif; font-stretch: normal; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: normal; position: absolute; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);">
      <li class="k-item js-second-level k-state-default k-first" role="menuitem">
        <a class="k-link js-second-level" href="..." target="">Reports / Analytics</a>
      </li>
      <li class="k-item js-second-level k-state-default" role="menuitem">
        <a class="k-link js-second-level" href="..." target="">User Requested</a>
      </li>
```

The XPath

```
//*[@id="menu"]/li[10]/div/ul/li[2]/a
```

The code

```
  echo "Switching to mainFrame\n";
  $driver->switchTo()->frame("mainFrame");
  echo "Finding link Reports/Analytics\n";
  //$input = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::partialLinkText('Reports/Analytics')); #didn't work
  $input = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="menu"]/li[10]/span'));
  $input->click();
  echo "Finding link User Requested\n";
  // $input = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::partialLinkText('User Requested')); # didn't work
  $input = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="menu"]/li[10]/div/ul/li[2]/a'));
  $input->click();
```

The error

```
Switching to mainFrame
Finding link Reports/Analytics
Finding link User Requested
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'NoSuchElementException' with message 'no such element
```

It seems no matter what I try, it won't work. There is no `id` for the link.

---

I managed to get *a* link clicked, but it selects the wrong link! I'm using Chrome to right click on the elements to get the CSS Path and XPath. (Some JavaScript sets an id `menu_mn_active` when a menu is selected.) The element shows the text is correct, but it is going to the wrong page.

```
  echo "Finding link User Requested\n";
  // $input = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::partialLinkText('User Requested'));
  // $input = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('#menu_mn_active > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a'));
  // $input = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="menu"]/li[10]/div/ul/li[2]/a'));  
  $input = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="menu_mn_active"]/div/ul/li[2]/a'));
  echo("Link text: ".$input->getText()."\n");  
  $input->click();
  echo "Finding link Export Employees To Bamboo\n";
```

Output

```
Finding link User Requested
Link text: User Requested
Finding link Export Employees To Bamboo
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'NoSuchElementException'
```

I also frequently get this error when trying to click the item in the slide down menu:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ElementNotVisibleException' with message 'element not visible
```

Comment: I don't see the `id` attribute in your HTML.

Comment: @zerkms The `#menu` id is ahead of the HTML given. I'll add it. The `<a>` has no `id`.

Comment: If you use `//*[@id="menu"]/li[10]/div/ul/li[2]/a` selector in chrome Elements tab and try to search using it - does it find anything?

Comment: If it cannot find it - then there is no element matching it. For tests I would **NEVER EVER** do what you just did - all xpaths must be written thoughtfully since that's how you "guarantee" your tests will run fine.

Comment: @zerkms Well, I used Chrome and right clicked on the element and selected 'Copy XPath' and that is how I got the XPath. I didn't know I could use find and XPaths though. Actually it DOES find the XPath when I use the full path. I don't have a choice of the HTML as that is what is presented and I don't have control over that.

Comment: I didn't mentioned to change html. My point is that for testing purposes you should write xpath manually and carefully, not just copy what chrome generates. Otherwise your tests will be fragile (and often hard to maintain). This `//*[@id="menu"]/li[10]/div/ul/li[2]/a` is just **OMG**, not sure how it could pass codereview from any senior QA engineer.

Comment: @zerkms It's not for testing. It's for integration with a site that doesn't have an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OMFG** It was because the size of the browser window that the Chrome driver pops up. The window is an odd shape that is narrower than normal and the element I was trying to click was ever so slightly out of the view port by a few pixels, even though it was clearly visible to me. When I manually adjusted the size of the window everything worked perfectly! I added this line near the beginning of the session and it works:

```
  $driver->manage()->window()->maximize();
```

Also it won't work if my mouse is hovering over the window! And I have to add a `sleep()` to wait for the menu to slide out. So brittle!

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify that xpath to the below. As others have said, it really is not a good idea using chrome to generate the xpath for you - or if you do apply some thought to it. In my experience chrome quite often does not generate the correct or most efficient xpath in all cases.

```
//a[contains(text(),'User Requested')]
```

Comment: That's great advice, but without changing the size of the browser it still gave `ElementNotVisibleException`.

Comment: I wasn't going to vote because it didn't help, and I had tried `partialLinkText` already, but I didn't know about that syntax for XPath and it was helpful for `<spans>` that do not qualify for `partialLinkText`.